# Create dynamical classnames with index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, insertafter

Can somebody tell me If I can create classnames with index in JS/JQuery(see example below)?

```
$(`<tr class='data${i}'><td id='value${i}'></td></tr>`).insertAfter('#tbl-geburtstage_row_title')
```

Here is the full code:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= Object.keys(birthdays).length; i++) {
            console.log(`query ${i}`)

            if ($(`tr.data${i}`).length & $(`#value${i}`).text() != "") {
                //$('td.data')[i].remove()
                //console.log('td.data' + [i] + ": successfuly added and filled")
            }
            else {
                if ($(`tr.data${i - 1}`.length)) {
                    $(`<tr class='data${i}'><td id='value${i}'></td></tr>`).insertAfter(`tr.data${i - 1}`)

                }
                else {
                    $(`<tr class='data${i}'><td id='value${i}'></td></tr>`).insertAfter('#tbl-geburtstage_row_title')


                }

            }
        }
```

Code Snippet:

```js
if ($(`tr.data${i}`).length & $(`#value${i}`).text() != "") {
  //$('td.data')[i].remove()
  //console.log('td.data' + [i] + ": successfuly added and filled")
} else {
  if ($(`tr.data${i - 1}`).length) {
    $(`<tr class='data${i}'><td id='value${i}'>First Line</td></tr>`).insertAfter(`tr.data${i - 1}`)

  } else {
    $(`<tr class='data${i}'><td id='value${i}'>First Line</td></tr>`).insertAfter('#tbl-geburtstage_row_title')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tbl-geburtstage">
  <tr id="tbl-geburtstage_row_title">
    <th class="tbl-geburtstage_th">Alles Gute zum Geburtstag wünschen wir...</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tbl-geburtstageWeekend">
  <tr id="tbl-geburtstageWeekend_row_title">
    <th class="tbl-geburtstage_th">Auch denen die letztes Wochenende Geburtstag hatten, alles Gute!</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where are your classname variables coming from? An array?

Comment: Are you asking if the code you have posted can be used.? Have you tried it?. I see no reason why it should not work.

Comment: No, from a for-loop statement

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Tested it multiple times even without any other dependencies.

Comment: @aleks8 You need to include what you have tried, like the forloop and the html. that way we can better help you

Comment: im struggling with the comment formatting 1sec haha

Comment: `if ($('tr.data${i - 1}'.length)) {} else { $("<tr class='data${i}'><td id='value${i}'></td></tr>").insertAfter('#tbl-geburtstage_row_title')`

Comment: @aleks8 Please don't post the code in the comment, use the edit button below your question. Second, please include all relevant code. Without the forloop and the relative html then we can't see whats going on.

Comment: @aleks8 This here is not correct `$('tr.data${i - 1}'.length)` i think you want `$('tr.data${i - 1}').length`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen shouldn't make a difference as the code gets executed in the else-instruction

Comment: @aleks8 you can try using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: What would be the point of using class names with an incrementing prefix? If they are all(?) unique, then why not use IDs to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe not relevant now, I want to fill the cells with content dynamicaly

Comment: Can somebody review the error message getting from the code snippet? Don't know what it tells me

Comment: As @CarstenLøvboAndersen pointed out you have a selector wrong. `$(\`tr.data${i - 1}\`.length)` should be `$(\`tr.data${i - 1}\`).length`. Notice the `)` moved before `.length`.

Comment: @aleks8 I have fixed the one error message in your snippet, you where missing a `}`, But as i have said 3 times now, we need your forloop. As you can see in the snippet `i` is not defined

Comment: `id` or `class` attributes that end in a sequential number are a code smell. Rarely that is the right solution for a problem. NB: the code snippet is not complete. It currently generates an error about `i`. Please fix.

Comment: Sorry for all the confusions I was messed up that day and in a hurry. Recently I had more time for it and solved it, thx for ur fast response people, appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

To use variables in string, in that case using index from a for loop, use ``

So, To create a class with index this is the correct way:

```
$('<tr class=`banana${i}`></tr>').insertafter('#id')
```